# Can't install Qt Creator on root partition

Tags: linux, qt, qt-creator

I can't install Qt Creator using online installer

> qt-unified-linux-x64-2.0.3-1-online.run

I set destination (/opt partition), I click next, I am asked for sudo password and then nothing happens. Zero progress.

I tried it on Kubuntu 16.04 before, I tried it on Antergos just a moment ago.

Everything works if I tell installer to install Qt Creator on /home partition though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should launch your installer under `sudo` privilege from command line instead, something like this:

```
sudo -s ./qt-unified-linux-x64-2.0.3-1-online.run
```